# How to use LZ4 compression in Linux 3.11

Tags: linux-kernel, compression, lz4

LZ4 algorithm was included in [Linux 3.11 kernel](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/?qt=grep&q=lz4)

Can I compress files with this algorithm without installation of additional packages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is referring to a kernel-side compression, for things like decompressing the kernel image itself.  For a write-up of the benefits, and comparison with existing kernel compression algorithms, see http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/lcjpcojp13_klee.pdf.

For compression/decompression of files from userspace, you need the userspace utility, which can be obtained from https://code.google.com/p/lz4/

Even for use of the LZ4 compressed kernel described in the first paragraph, you still need a userspace utility to compress your kernel file.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that LZ4 used internally and not available from userspace.  I found package for Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install liblz4-tool`.  After installation you can compress files with `lz4c -c source target.lz4`

Comment: Linux kernel uses legacy framing format. To generate a compressed file compatible with this format, you need the -l command.
(see lz4 -H, or man lz4, for more info).